# php: connecting to a database and and inserting a row of data

Tags: php, database

I just don't know what I;m doing wrong...  I have a php script that is supposed to insert values into my database, but everytime that the code hits this part of the script it hangs...

Im a newbie, I looked at tutorials online, but clearly I don't understand what Im doing wrong..

```
// Make a MySQL Connection
$link = mysql_connect("jdbc:mysql://mysqlx.server.net/MyDB", "MyUserName", "MyPassword");

//connect to my database
$link.mysql_select_db("TalesDB");

//insert 
$link.mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (ID, name, comment) VALUES(" +
                  $_GET['Key']  + ", '" +
                  $("#leaveComment").find("input").val() + "', '" +
                  $("#leaveComment").find("textarea").val() + "' ) ");
```

Please note that I use `$("#leaveComment").find("input").val()` and `$("#leaveComment").find("textarea").val() + "' ) ");` earlier in the script - and they are validated as text

Please help!  Any idea what Im doing wrong?

Comment: Are you perhaps mixing PHP and javascript?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you have mixed you JavaScipt and PHP together. The two can definitely work together but not like this :)

Use JQuery or just HTML forms to post data back to a server side script. You can use JQuery's ajax or post methods to accomplish this.

Then in your php script you can do something like this to insert a db record:

```
<?php

$con = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=127.0.0.1', 'username', 'password');

$stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `name`, `comment`) 
    VALUES (:id, :name, :comment)');

$stmt->bindParam(:id, $_POST['id']);
$stmt->bindParam(:name, $_POST['name']);
$stmt->bindParam(:comment, $_POST['comment']);

$result = $stmt->execute();

?>
```

I have used PHP PDO to connect and run the query. I'd recommend using it over mysql_query because of the security benefit of prepared statements. For more information take a look at the [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) documentation page.

An important thing to note is that the dollar sign $ is used for different purposes in JQuery and PHP. In JQuery it is a shorthand for the JQuery object and allows you to easily perform element selection. in PHP it is used to identify user declared variables.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, you expect too much from your humble PHP intepreter.

You're mixing `.`-style object access on a plain connection resource. And jQuery too.

For example instead of

```
$link.mysql_select_db("TalesDB");
```

you should do

```
mysql_select_db("TalesDB", $link);
```

Please recheck all the documentation from zero, don't confuse PHP with any other object-oriented platform, and certainly not with a (primarily) client-side one!

Answer (score 2):

You're using Javascript when you should be using php.

PHP is a [server-side](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_side_scripting) language, which means the php code will be executed before the HTML is sent to you.

Javascript is a [client-side](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side_scripting) language, which means the code will be executed after the page has been sent to you.

Answer (score 0):

i think, your problem is that you're trying to access DOM elements via jQuery on server side.
on server side you have $_GET and/or $_POST arrays with form parameters passed from client webbrowser to your server script